# Complex integral related to incomplete gamma function

Tags: integration, gamma-function, zeta-functions

In the study of the Riemann zeta function (the connection here is not really visible), I encountered in Titchmarsh book about the Riemann zeta function the integral

$$
\int_{N}^{\infty} \frac{\sin y}{y^{s+1}} dy.
$$
If i use integral by parts the power decrease but how can I obtain the integral.

In math wolfram it say is related to the incomplete gamma function.

I think an approach could be $sin(z)= e^{iz}-e^{-iz}/2i$ that came similar to gamma function but with complex values for e.

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively related to the incomplete gamma function.

Consider that you need the imaginary part of
$$\int \frac{e^{iy}}{y^{s+1}}\, dy$$ Change variable $y=ix$ to get 
$$I=i^{-s} \int \frac {e^x}{x^{s+1}}\,dx=-i^{-s}\,\Gamma (-s,x)$$ I do not think that you could avoid it.